# Syntax highlighting in terminal vim but not gVIM

Tags: vim, text-editor, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am currently using VIM in the terminal and have perfect syntax highlighting happening. But then when I try to use gvim no matter what type of file or how many times I type: ":syntax on" I don't get any syntax highlighting. Any ideas anyone?

Thank you.

Here is my .vimrc for those who are interested:

```
" Turn on pathogen for all plug-ins installed after 9/13/2010
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

" My color theme for vim
colors sorcerer

" Disable line wrapping for now
set nowrap

" Enable the mouse even when vi is used in the terminal
set mouse=a

" Since I use linux, I want this
let g:clipbrdDefaultReg = '+'

" This shows what you are typing as a command.  I love this!
set showcmd

" Automatically cd into the directory that the file is in
autocmd BufEnter * execute "chdir ".escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' ')

"Fix Vim's regex...
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v

" Gimme some breathing room at the bottom please...
set scrolloff=5

" makes vim usable with screen
set restorescreen

" Disable the arrow keys... helps the learning
map <up> <nop>
map <down> <nop>
map <left> <nop>
map <right> <nop>
imap <up> <nop>
imap <down> <nop>
imap <left> <nop>
imap <right> <nop>


"Kill error bells
set noerrorbells
set visualbell
set t_vb=

" Turn on spell check
" set spell

" Thesaurus!! 
set thesaurus+=/usr/share/myspell/dicts/mthesaur.txt

" Some NERDTree love
let NERDTreeBookmarksFile=expand("$HOME/.vim/NERDTreeBookmarks")

let NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
let NERDTreeHighlightCursorline=1
let NERDTreeShowFiles=1
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1

" Make swapping windows easier...
map <C-h> <C-w>h
map <C-j> <C-w>j
map <C-k> <C-w>k
map <C-l> <C-w>l

" Allow for buffers to be hidden so that they need not be closed to go to
" another file
set hidden

" Turn on incremental search
set incsearch
set smartcase

" Long history is long
set history=1000
set undolevels=1000

" No need for a vi backup file
set nobackup

" Colors!!
set t_Co=256

" Compatibility
set nocompatible

set formatprg=par

" Syntastic!!
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_loclist=1
let g:syntastic_quiet_warnings=0

" For soft wrapping text
command! -nargs=* Wrap set wrap linebreak nolist
set showbreak=…

" Sandro spacing preferences here
set number
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround

" Sandro key mapping here
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

"allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

set showmode "show current mode down the bottom

"Setting the status line...

set statusline=%f       "tail of the filename

"display a warning if the file format isn't Unix
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{&ff!='unix'?'['.&ff.']':''}
set statusline+=%*

"display a warning if file encoding isn't UTf-8
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{(&fenc!='utf-8'&&&fenc!='')?'['.&fenc.']':''}
set statusline+=%*

set statusline+=%h      "help file flag
set statusline+=%y      "filetype
set statusline+=%r      "read only flag
set statusline+=%m      "modified flag

"Syntastic!!
" set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
" set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
" set statusline+=%*


" Auto completion options
set wildmode=list:longest  "Change tab completion to be like Bash's
set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*~,*.swp,*.pyc "Files to ignore on auto complete

"display tabs and trailing spaces
set list

" Use the same symbols as TextMate for tabstops and EOLs
set listchars=tab:▸\•,extends:»,precedes:«,trail:•


let g:pydiction_location='~/.vim/after/ftplugin/pydiction/complete-dict'
set sm
set ai
let java_highlight_all=1
let java_highlight_functions="style"
let java_allow_cpp_keywords=1
set tags=~/.tags
set complete=.,w,b,u,t,i

command W w !sudo tee % > /dev/null

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shell slash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
"set shell slash

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
"set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*


" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
" let g:tex_flavor='latex'

filetype on        " enables filetype detection
filetype plugin on " enables filetype specific plug-ins
syntax on
filetype indent on " OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.


" VIM 7.3 features here...
if v:version >= 703
    set relativenumber
    set undofile
endif
```

Comment: anything in your `.gvimrc`? this stuff should just work, so you probably have some kind of odd config option.

Comment: I actually don't have a '.gvimrc'; do I need one?

Comment: really odd. maybe try another colorscheme?

Comment: I removed the scheme all together. Still nada.

Comment: it says - filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed once I finally figured out how to get gvim 7.3. Then the syntax highlighting magically came.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `:let g:colors_name` to see the name of the colourscheme that has been loaded, the value should be 'sorcerer', if it's not then something has gone seriously wrong

   - Type `:hi Operator`, you 'xxx' part should be coloured and you should see `guifg=<color>` in the output.
   - Put a new line at the top of your `.vimrc` containing just the word "`finish`", this will stop vim processing your `.vimrc`. Using `:colors default` and `:syntax on` should be enough to get syntax highlighting turned on. If this works then just move the `finish` line down through your `.vimrc` until you find the section that is breaking syntax highlighting.
   - On windows, gVim uses a file called `_vimrc`, so check for that as well.

Comment: I do get 'sorcerer' as the color theme. 'xxx' is colored. "Operator       xxx links to Statement" is the output that i get from the ':hi Operator' command. Even with ":colors default,:syntax on,finish" as the only three lines in my .vimrc, I still don't get the hightling. I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: The "finish" technique is simple and effective to try to know what is causing problems in a configuration. +1!

Answer (score 2):

When you type `:version` in gvim do you see `+syntax` listed in your features list?

Try comparing that to your regular Vim version.  Maybe your gvim build didn't include the syntax highlighting feature.

Comment: Nope, I definitely see the +syntax option. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's really odd, I'll poke around and see what else I can find.  It may be helpful if you post your .vimrc (gvim uses this as well as the .gvimrc)

Comment: Well it's up there now. Hopefully you find something ;)

Answer (score 2):

Building on Thien's response, I also had the same experience (`set syntax=on` fails, the menu options succeed but only until Vim is restarted).

The menu option apparently triggers `:syn=on`, and adding that to _vimrc does enable syntax highlighting persistently where `set syntax=on` did not. I'll leave it to someone with more experience to explain the difference between those two.

Answer (score 0):

`set syntax=xxx` was not working for me in gvim 7.3 on Windows XP although it did for vim in cygwin. To get syntax highlighting I had to go to **Menu > Syntax > Show filetypes in menu > select syntax**. I guess the menu command and the vim commands don't do the same thing with gvim on Windows.